# VBScript Expected End 800A03F6

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am getting this error while trying to run a VBScript (note this is not in a web environment - just running a VBScript on Windows):

```
Line: [Last line]
Error: Expected 'End'
Code: 800A03F4
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error
```

I think it is an If statement that is not closed correctly with an "End If," but I've gone through every instance of "If" in the code and cannot find the error. Any tips or tools that could help me figure out where/why this error is occurring?

Comment: Attaching the script would help... Use pastebin.com or similar if the script is too long to fit in the post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There was an "Else If" - there should be no space there: "Elseif"

[http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_conditionals.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/vbscript_conditionals.asp)

Hopefully this will help someone out in the future.

Comment: That solved my problem too.  Thanks for posting your resolution!

Answer (score 6):

In VBScript If is not the only token that requires an End.  Also look for **Function**'s and **Sub**'s without their appropriate end statements.